# How to assign different env variables to different processes in a Pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I was trying to assign different env variables to the processes in a Pool.

The only way I have found is to do sth. like the following code:

```
import os, multiprocessing

def init(env):
    os.environ = env
    os.environ['FOO'] = "foo_1"

def myfunc():
    print os.environ['FOO']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    child_env = os.environ.copy()
    child_env['FOO'] = "foo_2"
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init, initargs=(child_env,))
    child_env['FOO'] = "foo_3"
    for i in xrange(3):
        pool.apply_async(myfunc,()) # How to modify this line?
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

By doing this, all processes in the pool share the same env var `os.environ['FOO'] = "foo_1"` since they share the same initializer. How can I assign different values to `FOO` for different processes?

Output from above code:

```
foo_1
foo_1
foo_1
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than passing no args to myfunc, you can pass arguments to each:

```
def myfunc(myarg):
    child_env = os.environ.copy()
    child_env['FOO'] = "foo_{}".format(myarg)
    print child_env['FOO']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    child_env = os.environ.copy()
    child_env['FOO'] = "foo_2"
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init, initargs=(child_env,))
    child_env['FOO'] = "foo_3"
    for i in xrange(3):
        pool.apply_async(func=myfunc, kwds=dict(myarg=i)) # How to modify this line?
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I think that will get you at least half the way there.  The child function is now responsible for modifying its local environment if it needs to (perhaps it is running some subprocess that requires it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I have some reason which prevents me from passing arguments... So it can only be done through env vars (even pipes are not allowed).

Comment: can you get around that by having a wrapping function "myfunc_wrapper(myarg)" that sets up the environment then calls myfunc?